# Woocommerce website product name not showing full

Tags: wordpress, web, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site on the front page product title now show full it's show half title and then 3 dots pls anyone can fix this

My website
Woocommerce

I have tried to edit template but it's not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your installation but didn't spot any issues about the problem that you described.

Check screenshot: https://prnt.sc/BYr-zaTIk4Of

BUT, I have checked the whole site for any issues and I have see this:  https://prnt.sc/Hb61fv_wk0IP

Now if you this is your problem it's very simple. You have to edit your main .css file which is located in /wp-content/themes/elessi-theme/style.css and then search for ".nasa-show-one-line" and in this point delete the second rule which is "white-space: nowrap;" like screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/rWOLVKoRnsQg

Before you start to make any changes just remember to take a copy of your css file locally.

I hope to help you with this issue. If you need something else just inform me to take it to another step.

Friendly, George

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMi6w.jpg
I have attached Screenshot on the mobile view on the main shop page product title isn't showing full how to fix this and show full product title on home page

My website

Cosmeticsonlinehubb.pk

Comment: Also you're Screenshot links are broken

Comment: Hello Muhammad, im glad to complete your issue with fixing your css. Actually the solution that i gave you will fix both desktop and mobile views. I have check the screenshot urls and works perfect! If you need anything else i will stay with you to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with CSS. So one option is to check what happens there. Another option is to give us a live URL from your installation to check the problem. Sure it's simple to find a a solution.

-- You can check your theme's demos if it happens the same there like in your installation!

Comment: Thanks for the reply here is my website link cosmeticsonlinehubb.pk